# How do i prove this from Continuum hypothesis?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Under ZFC, let's assume Continuum hypothesis

> There exists an well-ordered set $W$ and a bijection $f:[0,1]\rightarrow W$ such that $\forall x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)$ has at most countable predecessors in $W$

How do i prove this?

Comment: What is your statement of the continuum hypothesis? What do you know about well-orderings? The question has a very easy answers if you know the right details, but otherwise a bit of work is needed to develop them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Take the least possible well-ordering of $[0,1]$.